# Up vote answer, so that OP can't delete question

Tags: discussion

I have seen many times that for silly questions, like typo graphical error or null reference error. Some user (*some times I can't stop my self as well*), quickly answer it. Now, almost every time we can simply close the question or down vote the question. By down voting or closing the question OP will come to know that there is something wrong with the question.

So, he has an option to delete the question. But what happens in most cases, the quick answer gets quick up vote as well, even knowing that this question is duplicate or something. I have seen this so many times. I know users are not obligated to justify their votes.

Isn't it the *bad* strategy of users to stop OP from deleting the answer ?

For example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32635322/getting-an-error-saying-expression-must-be-an-array-type-but-it-resolved-to-list) question has faced the same problem.

Comment: Strategy of whom? Certainly not the community, who'd want to see a typo-question disappear rapidly.

Comment: Why would you want to prevent users from deleting there posts if it is a silly question?

Comment: @CalebKleveter I wouldn't but this happened several times and that made me curious about it. Specifically why people waste their vote on this kind of answer ?

Comment: Have any examples?

Comment: The only person who would be interested would be the answerer. OP may give a vote (subject to enough reputation to do so), so someone after a badge, or.... but it's not a good thing.

Comment: [Here's another example.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32633436/can-anyone-help-me-with-my-rock-paper-scissors-game-in-java)

Comment: It is actually a pretty common practice to DV an answer to such a question.  To make sure it can be deleted easily, either by the OP or the roomba.  Can't do much about somebody upvoting it, you can certainly help reversing it by one.

Comment: @HansPassant I must agree. But one point is, tooltip on down vote  button says *This answer is not useful* which is not true in all such cases.

Comment: "Strategy" may not be what is going on here. Some users seem to upvote anything that is true. Answer: "2 + 2 = 4" Unrelated to the question, but what the heck, it is *true*!!! Upvote! Of course this means that such a user will upvote any correct answer to a typo-type question.

Comment: In fact, the answerer should clarify in a comment, and close vote or flag the question. Unfortunately there's a big number of rep hunters around here, that won't care about this policy. I'm with @Hans, downvote the answer, after flagging the question. Such stuff usually isn't helpful for anyone but the OP, and doesn't help for other researchers coming over it.

Comment: An answer that helps pollute Google query results with a silly typo problem is not useful to anyone.  It has to be useful to more than one person.

Comment: @Louis I strongly disagree that such answers are really upvote worthy. The question will be closed most probably anyways, and as soon it got enough downvotes, being deleted. It just makes the processing harder.

Comment: @HansPassant Yes. You are right, In that way down voting is  the right option.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ You do realize I was describing the thought process of *someone else* right? (In other words, when you say "I strongly disagree that such answers are really upvote worthy" you are not disagreeing with *me* but with *those users* who do find anything true to be worthy of an upvote.)

Comment: @Louis No, I didn't realize that. Well, sometimes irony or satire are hard to get from such comments.

Comment: I seen a lot of question marked as duplicated when in fact is the ANSWER which is duplicated and not the question (yes, answers may apply to multiple questions). In fact, usually because of a misunderstanding, but isn't any question about this? About some concept we do not know? -----
Also, to me SO is not an enciclopedia, the difference between a "what is wrong?" or "How to do that?" is usually just a matter of rewording. I feel sometime shame when a question is downvoted just because of incorrect wording or lack of good english.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, typo based questions almost always are an indication of low research efforts and help vampirism.

We don't want such questions, they won't help anyone else than the OP for the very moment.

Most of the time these kind of questions are heavily downvoted along, and good enough close voted for the appropriate policies reason:

> This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

So answering the question is in fact the wrong desired action.

Even if the code in question produces an unclear and voodoo spell like error message, someone who spots the cause could easily give a correction in a comment and down/close vote.

For the one's upvoting such answer, I don't believe that's based on some real *strategy*, but maybe just kind of admiration for the clever dude that was able to spot that typo, given the unclear or cryptic stuff.

Anyway as mentioned upvoting isn't the right action.

I personally usually just don't vote on such answers in either direction, but look forward to get the question closed and deleted as quickly as possible.