# Please allow us to self-delete questions for a short time even if an upvoted answer exists

Tags: feature-request, questions, vote-to-delete

In this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57287547/what-is-wrong-with-these-variadic-sums), the author (myself), asked quite silly typo question.
I wanted to delete it as soon as I noticed my mistake.

However, I could not, because one person had time to answer it and get a upvote for it, indeed:

> You cannot delete this question as others have invested time and
>   effort into answering it. For more information, visit the help center

I'm now a static and big downvote target, not that it bothers me (you can add a downvote if you like), but it's a quite polluting question on SO and, in my opinion, should be deleted.

Already discussed [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306278/up-vote-answer-so-that-op-cant-delete-question)

Could we have something, like the following, to prevent this from happening?

**before a 10 minutes delay, post could be deleted**

Eager to read your propositions.

Comment: I expected it to be in the [tag:android] tag but I see quality answers progressed to other tags as well ...

Comment: There you go, have a delete vote.

Comment: That didn't take long :-)

Comment: @MichaelBerry if you write an answer here it might get upvotes so this meta question is also locked for deletion ...

Comment: It's rather big of you to admit a mistake like that, so major kudos! I don't fault you for posting a question, we all get a blind spot at times. People should have just refrained from answering, really. In a perfect world....

Comment: The whole reason for this problem to exist is because one opinion of one person blocked deletion. The rule you propose moves that problem to the question, only one person needs to hastily upvote the question and you're stuck again.I think that makes things worse as there isn't even the necessity for someone writing an answer in between. Just allow stuff to be deleted within 15 minutes of creation - period. I'm extending the time a little to include a trip to the coffee machine or the toilet.

Comment: agreed. it's just a proposition ```before a 10 minutes delay, post could be deleted``` might be better.

Comment: Unfortunately, this likely would not work network-wide. For example, Math.SE has a problem where a user posts an obvious homework question, a well-meaning person answers it, and then the user deletes it before it can be upvoted.

Comment: @Kevin, I've seen that on SO too.  Still, I'm conflicted because the site was better off with the questions deleted anyway. (Otherwise, I would've lobbied for undeletion, etc.)

Answer (score 8):

I don't see this as a problem.  I think that this is the site working as it is intended.  The biggest issue is that you are now suffering from the downvotes you receive, which stinks.

Your post was closed as a typo.  I think that's a good thing.  Closure *should* prevent answers and hopefully the typo was pointed out in the comments which solves your problem.  Unfortunately, someone decided to point out the typo in an answer and then detail why it was a typo.  I don't usually tend to do that for this very reason.  I'll leave a comment.  I generally believe that if you can't explain the typo in a comment, it's probably not a minor typo and is probably a big enough issue that it could make for a good question.

I don't think that we should change this policy because it ends up costing us beneficial questions where a lot of effort goes into an answer but the OP deletes the question.  You see this a lot with homework questions where the OP tries to cover their tracks to avoid a teacher seeing their question.

See:

- [Make deleted posts searchable for 30 days](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/315355/691711)
- [What to do when a question you answered gets deleted intentionally?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/316117/691711)
- [Do we really need to keep closed typo questions with accepted/upvoted answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/273266/691711)

It stinks that you received downvotes, but a question like this could still find its way to being deleted through some other path like receiving enough delete votes.  I've never been clear on the reputation rules, but I think that a deletion within a certain time frame reverses reputation lost this way as well.

---

Potentially, I think that posts that are **explicitly** identified as typos should allow the OP to delete, no matter what the answers were or how they were voted on.  When something gets identified as a typo, it's usually small and as per the close description "unlikely to help future readers".

Changing the policy to be a 10 minute timeframe where the question can get deleted opens up the issues mentioned above.  If we identify the post as a typo, I think it should be fair game.

Comment: I like the suggestion to always allow a typo question to be deleted.  I was thinking the same thing.

Comment: or simply modify the roomba such that it ignores answers on questions closed as a typo.

Comment: @KevinB I just stumbled onto a question that asks for that which is the 3rd link I added.